# create a temp table with given columns and data

Tags: sql, postgresql, netezza, temp

I need to create a temp table with the data in table below in `Netezza`. The typical way I would create a temp table in `Netezza` is via

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE temp_table1 AS
(
 -- statement to fill the data
) DISTRIBUTE ON RANDOM;
```

How do I go about constructing the statement to be used inside so that the data below is available in the temp table ?

```
+---------+----------+
| bin_val |  bin_cnt |
+---------+----------+
|       0 |        2 |
|       4 |       10 |
|       8 |       15 |
|      12 |       12 |
|      16 |        6 |
|      20 |        1 |
+---------+----------+
```

A `PostgreSQL` solution would also be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
select v.*
from (values (0, 2), (4, 10), (8, 15), (12, 12), (16, 6), (20, 1)
     ) v(bin_val, bin_cnt)
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/9eecb/9008) is a SQL Fiddle.

This will probably not work in Netezza, because it uses a very old version of Postgres.  Instead, I think you can do:

```
select 0 as bin_val, 2 as bin_cnt union all
select 4, 10 union all
select 8, 15 union all
select 12, 12 union all
select 16, 6 union all
select 20, 1
```

Comment: tried this, however getting the following error - `ERROR [42000] ERROR:  'select v.* from (values (0, 2), (4, 10), (8, 15), (12, 12), (16, 6), (20, 1) ) v(bin_val, bin_cnt) LIMIT 1000'
error                            ^ found "(" (at char 25) expecting `CROSS' or `FULL' or `INNER_P' or `JOIN' or `LEFT'`

Comment: The simple select using union as you have suggested above is working fine. However `Netezza` gives error on creating a temp table with this data `CREATE TEMP TABLE t1 AS
(
select 0 as bin_val, 2 as bin_cnt union all
select 4, 10 union all
select 8, 15 union all
select 12, 12 union all
select 16, 6 union all
select 20, 1
) DISTRIBUTE ON RANDOM;` This gives error `ERROR [HY000] ERROR:  error creating sql object NZNVNPRD.NVN_DBO.T1`

Comment: wow - its wierd - for some reason `Netezza` doesn't like `t1` for temp table name. The following works `CREATE TEMP TABLE t2 AS
(
select 0 as bin_val, 2 as bin_cnt union all
select 4, 10 union all
select 8, 15 union all
select 12, 12 union all
select 16, 6 union all
select 20, 1
) DISTRIBUTE ON RANDOM;`

Answer (score -1):

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE MY_TABLE AS 
SELECT 
A,
B,
C
FROM 
DB1.TABLE1 
WHERE A NOTNULL
LIMIT 100;

------ DROP TABLE MY_TABLE

Comment: How does that work? They want specific values that's not in any current table.

Comment: sorry didn't look

Comment: sorry was in a rush at work and didn't look closely enough at question.

Comment: Hardcoded, it seems :) It seem to be the specific values that they want. Look at the other answer that's fetching those values only. Apart from that, you should probably also format code in a code block, and not use all caps. Presentation counts :) No need to be sorry. If you can fix it without using the same way as the other answer, then super!